# Why did the use of "if you shall" and "if you should" dramatically decline?

Tags: history, modal-verbs, historical-change, should, shall-future

Google Books statistics indicate that the use of the expression "if you should" and especially of the expression "if you shall" per unit of text length dramatically and steadily declined since the 1700s, as you can see in this [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if%20you%20should%2C%20if%20you%20shall&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20should%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0). As compared to the 1700s, the former expression is nowadays used about 7 times less frequently, and the latter expression - about 50 times less frequently.

Why did this happen?

My question is not meant to be broad or a request for subjective opinions. Instead, I mean to ask whether there are any obvious objective factors that explain or could explain such a decline, such as a documented change in the meaning or connotation. I am not a native speaker and do see any possible factors at all, so I hope that native speakers can shed some light.

My understanding is that the expression "if you shall/should" roughly means "if you have/had a duty or obligation to," and I am puzzled as to why the expression became so much less used to express the idea. I see nothing wrong or weird in saying, "I will help you find another apartment and relocate to it if you shall vacate your current landlord's property by the end of this month."

In an attempt to find the answer, I looked at statistics for the expressions "you should" and "you shall" (i.e., without "if"). I found that although the use of the latter expression considerably declined since the 1700s (by a factor of 10), the use of the former one did not decline at all: [Graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20should%2C%20you%20shall&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20should%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20shall%3B%2Cc0). Thus, the statistics of "you shall/should" cannot explain the magnitude of the decline of the use of "if you shall/should." And I even do not see why the expression "you shall" became less frequently used than before.

I am puzzled and humbly hope to read enlightening responses by native speakers.

---

Update: As pointed out by JK2 in an answer below, the statistics are different if we replace "if" by "If" (i.e., if we make the first letter capital):

- The use of "If you should" (with the capital letter I in "If") is nowadays about 4 times less frequent per unit of text length as compared to the middle of the 1800s.
- The use of "If you shall" (with the capital letter I in "If") is nowadays about 20 times less frequent per unit of text length than in the 1700s and 1800s.

Thus, the decline for these phrases with the capital letter I is less dramatic than for the same phrases with the small letter i, but is still very considerable.

Comment: Consider that in the 1700s very few novels were being published, and the closest thing to a "magazine" was *Poor Richard's Almanac*.  Most writing from the era that has survived long enough to be scanned into Google Books was stodgy formal stuff.

Comment: I had a theory that they were replaced by *if you would*, but adding that term to the graph didn't result in any support for the theory . . . (I only found out that it's almost always been the more common of the three.)

Comment: All things subjunctive have declined. These *if* conditionals take a subjunctive construction, and we just have rearranged things to not use them as much anymore. Plus *shall* has narrowed in terms of its meaning and usage. "*If you shall be so kind* as to pass me the marmalade" just isn't what we say anymore. (4 hits for this construction on Google since 2010, plus my mom, who doesn't blog.)

Comment: American vs British differences anyone?

Comment: _Shall_ is not used in American English except in the fixed expressions _Shall I `VP`_ (an offer by the speaker to do `VP` -- _Shall I open the window?_) and _Shall we `VP`_ (an invitation to do `VP` with the addressee -- _Shall we dance?_). _Should_ is common, but its usage is quite variable.

Comment: *Shall* is common in law and executive orders, e.g. “Within 180 days of the date of this memorandum, the Secretary shall report to the Director of the Office of Science and Technology Policy recording DOI’s progress in identifying the assets that can be used to support rural broadband deployment and adoption.”

Comment: @Mitch No, merely a very old way of forming certain kinds of conditionals. *Vide infra.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the transition into and out of Early Modern English, so really a very long time ago, people would write *if you shall* with the modal *shall* followed by some verb in its plain form to convey the same sense where today we would omit the modal altogether. The following all mean essentially the same thing:

1. If you shall see him, you shall lend him a thousand pounds.
2. If you should see him, you shall lend him a thousand pounds.
   Should you see him, you shall lend him a thousand pounds. (*same but with inversion*)
3. If you happen to see him, you must lend him a thousand pounds.
4. If you see him, lend him a thousand pounds.

Number 1 is completely obsolete, while number 2 is quite stuffy and formal but hardly obsolete. Even number 3 is a bit wordy. Number 4 is the ordinary way to express that today.

On pages 313 and 314 of [*The History of Scotland: During the Reigns of Queen Mary and of King James VI. Until His Accession to the Crown of England: with a Review of the Scottish History Previous to that Period; and an Appendix Containing Original Papers, Volume 3*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ER8wAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA313&dq=%22if+you+shall%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ4vGVqv7iAhVPVs0KHR8vD3M4ChDoAQhbMAk#v=onepage&q=%22if%20you%20shall%22&f=false), we find two examples of this construction in a letter from Queen Mary dated the Twelfth of September of the year 1566. (Because that year is from before the adoption of the Gregorian calendar, it would, I believe, be the Twenty-Third of that same month according to our current way of reckoning such things.)

Here is the first, from page 313:

[image: page 313 of said tome]

The salient sentence is this one: (Yes, it's really just one sentence!)

> **If you shall certainly understand** that the Earl of Murray hath such want of money, as the impresting to him of one thousand pounds might stand him in stead for the help to defend himself, you shall presently let him secretly to understand, that you will, as of yourself, let him have so much, and so we will that you let him have, in the most secret sort that you can, when the said sum shall come to you, or if you can, by any good means advance him some part therefore beforehand.

Today we might start that saying: *If you come to understand with certainty that...*

The second example occurs in this sentence from the next page:

[image: page 314 example]

Where that sentence is:

> But now, considering we take it, that they are pursued, notwithstanding their humble submission and offer to be ordered and tied by law and justice, which being refused to them, they are retired to Dumfrese, a place near our west marches, as it seemeth there to defend themselves, and adding thereunto the good intention that presently the French King pretendeth, by sending one of his to join with some one of ours, and jointly to treat with that Queen, and to induce her to forbear this manner of violent and rigorous proceeding against her subjects, for which purpose the French ambassador here with us has lately written to that Queen, whereof answer is daily looked for; to the intent in the mean time the said lords should not be oppressed and ruined for lack of some help to defend them, we are content and do authorize, **if you shall see** it necessary for their defence, to let them (as of your adventure, and without notifying that you have any direction therein from us) to have the number of 300 soldiers, to be taken, either in bands, or to be drawn out of all your bands, as you shall see cause.

In other words, *If you see it as something that’s necessary for their defence, we authorize you to...*

Again, this *if you shall* style of writing conditionals passed out of common use for what we today use just the plain present tense for without a modal, or on rare occasion via *if you should (happen to) ....*

I hope it is clear that we no longer write the way they did back then. :)

Comment: One sentence? Goddam you smartphone, twitter, and instagram.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer. Your conclusion is this:  "we no longer write the way they did back then." And I am curious as to WHY you no longer write the way you did back then :) What caused the change? :)

Comment: My own wild guess was this: As "shall" essentially expresses a duty or obligation, people used to often say "shall" in the past to emphasize that they did things because they were obliged or had a duty. People simply used to think in terms of duties or obligations. Nowadays the mentality seems to have changed, and people seem to be more positive and to think in terms of wishes and desires rather than duties and responsibilities. The decline of "you shall" as well as "if you shall/should" seems to reflect this shift. But this is just my wild guess.

Comment: @Mitsuko I don't think it's the deontic sense of the modals we're looking at here, but rather the epistemic sense. That means obligation is not involved, only probability. You should therefore look for inverted conditionals case insensitively: *shall you, should you, shouldst thou*. Notice how now the middle one is perfectly commonplace. Add an infinitive like *have* or *be* for specific scenarios.

Comment: @Mitsuko [Consider this graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Shall+you%2C+Should+you%2C+Shouldst+thou&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CShall%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CShould%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CShouldst%20thou%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the "dramatic decline" may be due to your failing to capitalize "if" in the Ngram, because "if" can be an interrogative marker (meaning *whether*) as well as a conditional marker, whereas "If" can only be the latter.

The decline of "If you shall" is not as dramatic as that of "if you shall" as shown in [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If%20you%20shall%2Cif%20you%20shall&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIf%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CIf%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0). This is also the case with "If/if you should" as shown in [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If%20you%20should%2Cif%20you%20should&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIf%20you%20should%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20should%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CIf%20you%20should%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20should%3B%2Cc0).

In other words, searching "if" instead of "If" is basically conflating the two different constructions, thereby making the search results too complicated to analyze.

Comment: According to this Ngram chart the difference is indeed dramatic https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+you+shall%2C&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CIf%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bif%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIf%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2CIf%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bif%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc1%3B%3BIf%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc1 "If you shall" (uppercase/green) is far lower than its lowercase counterpart.

Comment: All the following "**if you shall**" vs. "**if I shall**" and "**if you should**" vs "**if I should***" are seemingly on the decrease  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+you+shall%2Cif+I+shall%2C+if+you+should%2C+if+I+should&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20should%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20should%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20shall%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20shall%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20should%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20should%3B%2Cc1

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but "I shall" is not to be compared with "you shall" because the former is still in use in BE whereas the latter is not either in BE or AE.

Comment: My point being is  the Ngram link in my comment shows the phrase "If I shall" is also in decline, if we are to take its word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Honestly, I don't understand the "case insensitive" option of the Ngram. I think my Ngram is clear enough to prove my point, i.e., "if you shall" _is_ declining, but not as dramatically as the OP erroneously makes it out to be declining.

Comment: Look at the results on the bottom of the graph, many of the istances come from [grammar books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20you%20shall%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) or from The Bible. The capitalization of "If" makes little difference, it's the construction "If/if you shall/should" that is in sharp decline

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think I've heard that the instances below the Ngram have nothing to do with the Ngram itself.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken but if you can find the reference that confirms your suspicion I would be very intetested to read it. As far as I know, the results are taken from Google Books

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm afraid you're mistaken about it. Here's what 'About Ngram Viewer' says: "Note that the Ngram Viewer is case-sensitive, but Google Books search results are not." https://books.google.com/ngrams/info

Comment: You're mistaken about the statement you made earlier; i.e. the instances below Ngram have *nothing* to do with Ngram itself. The uppercase and lowercase instances are grouped together in the results.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The fact that the Ngram Viewer is case-sensitive, but Google Books search results are not _proves_ that the GB search results are pooled from a different source than the source from which the Ngram is drawn. So I'll have to stand by my statement. Moreover, the current issue is specifically about comparing "If" and "if", so simply looking at the GB search results isn't a terribly reliable way to second-guess the Ngram itself.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable observation. I just looked at your statistics. The use of "If you should" (with the capital letter I in "If") is nowadays about 4 times less frequent as compared to the middle of the 1800s. The use of "If you shall" (with the capital letter I in "If") is nowadays about 20 times less frequent than in the 1700s and 1800s. So yes, for these phrases (with the capital letter I) the decline is less dramatic than for "if you shall" and "if you should" (with the small letter i), but is still very considerable. A factor of 20 is a big number.

Comment: My impression is that in the past it was common to write very long sentences with multiple commas and semicolons, and this might partially explain the difference in the decline between "if you shall/should" and "If you shall/should." That is, it was usual to write "if you shall" after a semicolon, whilst nowadays people would simply make a full stop instead of a semicolon and then write "If you shall" starting with the capital letter I.

Comment: Your answer seems to indirectly imply that one of the main reasons for the decline of "if you shall" and "if you should" (with the small letter i) is that those phrases ceased to be frequently used to mean "whether you shall/should." That is, "if" is nowadays replaced by "whether," but was not replaced in the past. This is an interesting hypothesis indeed. But I never saw any article saying that "whether" is a modern word or was not frequently used centuries ago.

Comment: Anyway, you made a valuable observation, and I just added an update to my post to refer to your observation.

Comment: @Mitsuko You must be misunderstanding how Ngram works. I suggest you read the second paragraph of 'About Ngram Viewer': "...What the y-axis shows is this: of all the bigrams contained in our sample of books written in English and published in the United States, what percentage of them are "nursery school" or "child care"?..." https://books.google.com/ngrams/info This means that the frequency change in a single graph of "If you shall" over time is not absolute but only relative to all the trigrams at a certain time.